# owl carousel is displaying all items in a bad way

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm trying to make only three items appears on the screen
but I get them aligned in a bad way they are four in one row under each other
I want them like this:

[image: I want them like this]

but they appear like this

[image]

in both cases, the owl slider is working in the grab event and sliding but showing the two Rows when the items are more than 3

here is my HTML code

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme owl-responsive-1441 owl-loaded" style="opacity: 1;">

<div class="owl-stage-outer"><div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0.25s ease 0s; width: 1440px;"><div class="owl-item active" style="width: auto; margin-right: 0px;"><div class="row">
<div class="item col-12 col-md-4">
<div href="/VCP/site_vcp/public_html/consultingdd/" class="item-content">
<span class="image"><img src="/VCP/site_vcp/public_html/uploads/files/Couns_Home_page_icon.png" alt="image"></span>
<span class="brief">
<h4>consultingdd</h4>
<p>test test</p>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item col-12 col-md-4">
<div href="/VCP/site_vcp/public_html/consulting6622/" class="item-content">
<span class="image"><img src="Couns_Home_page_icon.png" alt="image"></span>
<span class="brief">
<h4>consulting6622</h4>
<p>test test kjkjhkjhkjh
asdasd
asdasda
asd</p>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item col-12 col-md-4">
<div href="/VCP/site_vcp/public_html/consulting66/" class="item-content">
<span class="image"><img src="Couns_Home_page_icon.png" alt="image"></span>
<span class="brief">
<h4>consulting66</h4>
<p>test test kjkjhkjhkjh</p>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item col-12 col-md-4">
<div href="/VCP/site_vcp/public_html/consulting/" class="item-content">
<span class="image"><img src="Couns_Home_page_icon.png" alt="image" style="opacity: 1;"></span>
<span class="brief">
<h4>consulting</h4>
<p>test test</p>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div></div></div></div><div class="owl-controls"><div class="owl-nav"><div class="owl-prev" style="display: none;">prev</div><div class="owl-next" style="display: none;">next</div></div><div class="owl-dots" style=""><div class="owl-dot active"><span></span></div></div></div></div>
```

and here is my javascript code

```
 if ($(".our-services  .owl-carousel").length) {
        $('.our-services  .owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:true,
            autoplay:true,
            autoplayTimeout:5000,
            lazyLoad: true,
            // items:3,
            autoWidth: true,
            responsiveClass:true,
            nav: false,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1
                },
                424: {
                    items: 1
                },
                768: {
                    items: 2
                },
                991: {
                    items: 2
                },
                1199: {
                    items: 2
                },
                1441: {
                    items: 3
                },
                1990:{
                    items: 3
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code seems to be the one generated dinamically by Owl Carousel, if that's the case, please put your original static HTML code. If not, try using the following:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">

  <div class="item">
    <div href="/VCP/site_vcp/public_html/consultingdd/" class="item-content">
      <span class="image"><img src="/VCP/site_vcp/public_html/uploads/files/Couns_Home_page_icon.png"
          alt="image"></span>
      <span class="brief">
        <h4>consultingdd</h4>
        <p>test test</p>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div href="/VCP/site_vcp/public_html/consulting6622/" class="item-content">
      <span class="image"><img src="Couns_Home_page_icon.png" alt="image"></span>
      <span class="brief">
        <h4>consulting6622</h4>
        <p>test test kjkjhkjhkjh
          asdasd
          asdasda
          asd</p>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div href="/VCP/site_vcp/public_html/consulting66/" class="item-content">
      <span class="image"><img src="Couns_Home_page_icon.png" alt="image"></span>
      <span class="brief">
        <h4>consulting66</h4>
        <p>test test kjkjhkjhkjh</p>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item ">
    <div href="/VCP/site_vcp/public_html/consulting/" class="item-content">
      <span class="image"><img src="Couns_Home_page_icon.png" alt="image" style="opacity: 1;"></span>
      <span class="brief">
        <h4>consulting</h4>
        <p>test test</p>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```